# js appending html to table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im currently adding to cell in the table like this:

```
var cell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
  var text = document.createTextNode('hello');
  var makeTextBold = document.createElement('b');
  makeTextBold.appendChild(text);
  cell.appendChild(makeTextBold);
```

Which does work fine, was wondering is there a way not as messy as this, as some cell will have `<br>`,`<b>` and `<i>` in them. Is there way for something similar as:

```
var cell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
var html= '<b>hello</b>;
cell.itsHtml = html;
```

Or even:

```
var cell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
var html= '<b>hello</b>;
cell.html(html.compiled..)
```

I cannot use `document.findelementbyid('id').innerHtml`, as few cells will have the same id (as I have to put date as Id).
Thanks!

Comment: "_few cells will have the same id_" ..? Ids are supposed to be unique within the document. Can't you add a class, and bold the text in the cell with CSS? That way you don't need to create any elements or textnodes, just set `cell.textContent`.

Comment: Among other problems one reason you can't use "*I cannot use `document.findelementbyid('id').innerHtml`*" is that neither of those methods exist. Can you reproduce enough of your code that we can see the HTML you're working with, and the type of changes you want to make? Please read both the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines, then [edit] your question.

Comment: Duplicated IDs? ...plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) jQuery function and get the table as the object via it's id or class.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pobqtdj7/) or the snippet below.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#myButton").on("click", function() {
        $('#myTable > tbody').append('<tr><td>08/28/2020</td><td>joe</td></tr>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>date</td>
      <td>name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>08/28/2020</td>
      <td>joe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>

<input type="submit" id="myButton">
```